# Call to undefined method decodeResponseJson() in PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I try to run simple validation test:

```
private function orderTickets($concert, $params)
{
    $this->json('POST', "/concerts/{$concert->id}/orders", $params);

}

 /** @test */

public function email_is_required_to_purchase_tickets()
{


    $concert = factory(Concert::class)->create();

    $this->orderTickets($concert, [

        'ticket_quantity' => 3,
        'payment_token' => $this->paymentGateway->getValidTestToken()
    ]);

    $this->assertResponseStatus(422);

    $this->assertArrayHasKey('email', $this->decodeResponseJson());

}
```

At the last line I need to assert that json has key 'email'.
But when I run it I get this message:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\PurchaseTicketsTest::decodeResponseJson()
```

Do I need to import anything into my Laravel project for this to work?

Seems like this method is unknown at all.

I am on Laravel 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decodeResponseJson` is part of `Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse`, not `TestCase`. I changed your `orderTickets` method to return the response so it can be used in the test.

```
private function orderTickets($concert, $params): TestResponse
{
    return $this->json('POST', "/concerts/{$concert->id}/orders", $params);
}

/** @test */
public function email_is_required_to_purchase_tickets()
{
    $concert = factory(Concert::class)->create();

    $response = $this->orderTickets($concert, [
        'ticket_quantity' => 3,
        'payment_token' => $this->paymentGateway->getValidTestToken()
    ]);

    self::assertEquals(422, $response->getStatusCode());
    self::assertArrayHasKey('email', $response->decodeResponseJson());
}
```

Comment: it gives: TypeError: Return value of Tests\Feature\PurchaseTicketsTest::orderTickets() must be an instance of Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse, none returned

Comment: Interesting. What's the inheritance path of your test case, @PinPiguin
With Laravel 7 it should be something like this: `YourTest` -> `Tests\TestCase` -> `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`?

Comment: This is what I have : namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Billing\FakePaymentGateway;
use App\Billing\PaymentGateway;
use App\Concert;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Testing\Assert as PHPUnit;
use Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse;
use Tests\TestCase;

Comment: Hmm. Did you change the line `$this->json('POST', "/concerts/{$concert->id}/orders", $params);` to `return $this->json('POST', "/concerts/{$concert->id}/orders", $params);` in `orderTickets`?

Comment: The whole file is here: https://pastebin.com/5yCcSgYJ

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not reproduce the error. I pasted your code into a new laravel (7.22.4) project and it worked straight away. If you put your tests/TestCase.php on pastebin, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: This is this contents of TestCase.php https://pastebin.com/BQkUC5q6   .Thank you for looking.

Comment: Alright. Please change `use Laravel\BrowserKitTesting\TestCase as BaseTestCase;` to `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;`.

Comment: And now it worked! Got pass! Kindly advise where to look such things up? I must be looking at the wrong documentation source ...

Comment: When things don't work as expected, try to isolate what you are working on and reduce it to the absolute minimum. I took your test case, put it in a fresh laravel project and removed everything unnecessary. Since it worked, there had to be a minor difference. That's why I asked for the inheritance path. If I was more familiar with laravel I probably would have known that the testing approach was different in previous versions. You basically had a base class to enable tests in the style of laravel 5.3. If you started off a fresh 7, you maybe just looked at the wrong documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on the same "Test Driven Laravel" course you are and had the same problem due to the course being written for Laravel 5.x. There's actually a more convenient way to solve this problem using newer Laravel 7 testing functions. Instead of decoding the response and checking it with assertArrayHasKey, you can just call assertJsonValidationErrors directly on the response (the resposne is already inheriting from \lluminate\Testing\TestResponse). Here's the full code of that test function...

```php
    /** @test */
    public function email_is_required_to_purchase_tickets(){

        $paymentGateway = new FakePaymentGateway;
        // Bind the FakePaymentGateway class to the PaymentGateway interface 
        // so we can type hint the interface in the controller methods. This
        // should probably be moved to a service provider though. 
        $this->app->instance(PaymentGateway::class, $paymentGateway);

        // Create a concert
        $concert = factory(Concert::class)->create();

        // Purchase concert tickets
        $this->json('POST', "/concerts/{$concert->id}/orders", [
            'ticket_quantity' => 3,
            'payment_token' => $paymentGateway->getValidTestToken(),
        ]);

        // Laravel uses response code 422 for validation error responses
        $this->assertResponseStatus(422);

        // Assert that the json response contains an email validation error. 
        $this->response->assertJsonValidationErrors('email');

    }
```